# Api First and Single Page Application

Tags: security, rest, web, oauth, single-page-application

I'm building a single page application and a REST API  to handle requests from the client and any possible third party client.

My idea is to create three servers :

- A - The API, OAuth based
- B - A static with the html/css/js files + partials/views
- C - A web server (node or python or anything) who handles the login

Possibly a fourth one handling sessions with Redis or anything else.

I want the SPA to make the user register and/or login to the server C, give him an access token and let him directly talk to the API (A).

My question is what is the right mechanism to handle this?

- To set a session cookie, with the access token inside, to the main application client (the SPA), so it can talk to the REST API as long as the session lives
- To avoid creating the server C and handling authentication in the server A, (what about third party services then?)
- Anything else

My question is a bit messy, so feel free to ask me for more details.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago, but did not get much feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362639/how-to-do-authentication-with-a-single-page-app-and-api-backend - i would suggest start simple(r) however...

Comment: Yes, i've already seen that question and many more but unfortunatly it didn't sound clear enough for me. What do you mean by "simple(r)"?

Comment: leave OAuth out for the start... maybe you can use just signed requests?

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically describing is a "ticketing" system, only you're calling the ticket a "token."  This problem has been dealt with in different ways with different standardized protocols for a number of years.  A very popular, and open standard developed at MIT is [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29).

If possible I would highly recommend using an existing protocol and an existing implementation.  Trying to "roll your own" security is very, very difficult, and usually results in a vulnerable app.  Think about the plagues that have riddled Microsoft over the years, compared to the relatively secure reputation of *nix systems :-)

My first approach would be to adopt Kerberos or another similar protocol.  If you are dead set on rolling your own, then the simpler the better.  I would go with something like your second solution and scrap server C.  There is too much room for error when letting a different server perform the authentication.

I know this isn't exactly the answer you were hoping for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to setup a ticketing system but a good way to handle authentication for my system. I've just discovered the world of single page apps and i wonder how to deal with security and auth. Thanks for your answer btw :)